# Poésie : Ponctuation et e muet

Tags: prononciation, ponctuation, poésie

J'aimerais savoir si un e muet pouvait se prononcer en l'influençant par la ponctuation ?

Par exemple si j'invente un vers :

> Mon aimée éternelle, es-tu déjà partie ?

Doit-on compter le e final de "éternelle" ou non, étant donné qu'on marque une pause avant le "es-tu" ?

Est-ce aussi le cas si on change la virgule en un point virgule, ou en un point tout court ?

Comment: Non, la ponctuation ne permet pas de le prononcer même si ça fait une coupure (personnellement c'est plutôt le raisonnement inverse que j'aurais eu : est-ce que placer une virgule permet de ne pas prononcer le e malgré une consonne qui suit ? Et c'est non également il me semble).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En poésie, en général, on prononce le E muet si le mot suivant commence par un son consonne (y compris un H aspiré), et on ne le prononce pas si le mot suivant commence par un son voyelle. La présence de ponctuation à l'intérieur du vers ne change pas cette règle générale.

En fin de vers, on ne prononce pas le E muet — il ne compte pas dans le nombre de syllabes — mais un vers qui se termine par un E muet ne rime pas avec un vers qui ne se termine pas par un E muet : on parle de rime féminine ou masculine. Une finale qui se termine par une voyelle suivie d'un E (*allée*, *finie*, *vue*, …) est aussi féminine.

Ces règles générales admettent des exceptions. Une part de l'art du poète est de savoir quand respecter les règles et quand dévier à bon escient.

Voici quelques alexandrins (12 syllabes) de Victor Hugo (tirés de *La Légende des siècles*) qui illustrent ces règles. Les **e** gras sont prononcés, les [e] entre crochets sont muets. J'ai aussi indiqué par une barre oblique les di/érèses (prononciation en deux syllabes d'un mot qui serait habituellement prononcé avec une diphtongue).

« Puissance égale bonté »

> Et l'ouragan l'aidait, étant démon lui-mêm[e].
>    L'Êtr**e**, parlant du haut du firmament suprêm[e],
>    Dit:--Que veux-tu de plus?--Et le grand pari/a,
>    Levant sa têt[e] énorme et trist**e**, lui cria:

> Voici tout ce que j'ai. Je te le donn**e**. Prends.

« Au Lion d'Androclès »

> Femm**e** gross**e**, vieillard débil[e], enfant qui tett[e],
>    Captifs, gladi/ateurs, chrétiens, étaient jetés
>    Aux bêt**e**s, et, tremblants, blêm**e**s, ensanglantés,
>    Fuyaient, et l'agonie effarée et vivant[e]
>    Se tordait dans le cirqu[e], abîm**e** d'épouvant[e].

Un peu plus loin dans « Au Lion d'Androclès », on trouve des déviations :

> Ju/ifs sans langu[e], poltrons sans poings, larrons sans yeux;
>    Ainsi que dans le cirqu**e** atroce et furieux

On pourrait dire « juifs·sans·lan·gu**e** » mais le rythme serait décalé par rapport aux deux autres groupes (1 2 sans 3), donc je pense qu'il faut lire « juifs » avec deux syllabes et « langue » avec une seule. Dans le second vers, « atroce et furieux » ne compte que 5 syllabes. On ne peut pas faire de diérèse sur « furieux » car cela briserait la rime avec « yeux », il faut donc prononcer soit le E de « cirque » soit celui d'« atroce ». Je trouve que « Ain·si·que·dans·le·cirqu | e·a·troce·et·fu·rieux » sonne mieux que « Ain·si·que·dans·le·cirque | a·tro·ce·et·fu·rieux » mais je n'ai pas d'argument solide pour cette préférence.

Comment: Je découperais les derniers vers comme ceci : « juifs·sans·lan·gue|...» et « Ain·si·que·dans·le·cirque | a·troce·et·fu·ri·eux » Racine n'a pas de scrupules à faire rimer yeux et furieux: « L'onde approche, se brise, et vomit à nos yeux, || Parmi des flots d'écume, un monstre furieux. »

Answer (score 5):

En poésie, et uniquement dans ce contexte, tout mot se terminant par un ***e*** habituellement muet comme ici l'adjectif *éternelle* se prononce *éternell**eu*** quand il est suivi d'une syllabe commençant par une consonne ou un ***h*** aspiré, mais uniquement dans ce cas. S'il est suivi par une syllabe commençant par une voyelle, le ***e*** final ne sera jamais prononcé. La présence d'une ponctuation n'affecte pas cette règle.

Voici en revanche un exemple d'alexandrin où ce ***e*** est prononcé :

> Tout aimer, et, Dieu bon ! incessamment traduire,
>
> Pour l'œil intérieur comme pour l'œil charnel,
>
> L'éternelle pensée en spectacle éternel ?

Victor Hugo, *Les Rayons et les Ombres*

Comment: Réponse évidemment exacte mais pas assez générique à mon avis, il demandait si, de manière générale, la ponctuation en plein milieu d'un vers, entre un e muet et un mot commençant par une voyelle, pouvait obliger la prononciation du e.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Précision ajoutée à ma réponse. merci !

Comment: Bonjour, Lorsque vous écrivez "En poésie, et uniquement dans ce contexte", voulez-vous dire que dans la récitation prosodique (texte non versifié, mais simplement déclamé) cette règle ne s’applique pas ?
Je vous remercie d’avance.

Comment: @Kambro En prose, on est libre de prononcer ou pas un *E* caduc.

Answer (score 2):

En fait littéralement, la ponctuation n'a aucun impact. Si la ponctuation autorisait la prononciation du "e", il y aurait heurt de 2 voyelles : les règles de la poésie cherchent à faciliter / fluidifier la lecture, c'est pourquoi on lit les e entre 2 consonnes, comme dans chacun des cas suivants "Lai**sse(nt) p**iteu**sem**ent leurs gran**des** ailes blanches" SS-E-P / S-E-M / D-E-S (s prononcé à cause de la liaison).
Les seules règles à respecter sont :

- le "e" est caduc en fin de vers (donc pas prononcé s'il est la dernière lettre du mot ou suivi exclusivement de lettres muettes)
- le "e" est muet devant une voyelle ou un h muet suivi d'une voyelle
- le "e" est prononcé entre 2 consonnes, soit à l'intérieur d'un mot s'il est directement précédé est suivi par 2 consonnes qui se prononcent (y compris "h") ; en fin de mot quand il est directement précédé par une consonne et est suivi par une autre consonne habituellement muette mais que la liaison s'impose (donc devant un mot commençant par une voyelle) ;  à la fin d'un mot lorsqu'il est directement précédé par une consonne et suivi par un mot commençant par une consonne.

La ponctuation ne peut pas changer ces règles. Dans les vers libres, cependant, les e sont prononcés selon l'humeur de la personne, mais il n'y a pas de règles dans les vers libres, cette question paraît donc logiquement relative aux vers réguliers.