# Prononciation de -oie terminée avec un [-j] ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire

En lisant une transcription phonétique dans la partition chorale de la Valse et Chœur, un extrait de l'opéra Faust écrit par Jules Barbier et Michel Carré (musique par Charles Gounod) au XIXe siècle, j'ai découvert deux mots transcrits étrangement.

Ce sont les mots *« tournoie »* (dans le vers : *la terre tournoie*) et *« joie »*. Dans l'originale français, ils sont écrits sous trois notes comme *tour-noi-e* et sous deux notes comme *joi-e* respectivement. Leurs transcriptions phonétiques : *[tuʁ-nwa-jə]* et *[ʒwa-jə]*.

Je comprends que celles ne sont pas les prononciations modernes, mais était-il possible de prononcer les mots finissant par *-oie* avec un *[-j]* terminal dans le français de XIXe ou peut-être XVIe siècle quand la première traduction de *l'Historia von Johann Fausten* a été née ?

Comment: Comme tu le sais sans doute, le e muet [ə] est prononcé pour compléter la phrase musicale. Le [j] n'est que le « glissement » entre les deux voyelles. C'est-à-dire qu'en articulant [a] puis [ə] sans hiatus, la langue produira de façon presque inévitable un [j]. C'est mon avis en tout cas ; je laisse un peu de temps au cas ou quelqu'un d'autre présente une meilleure explication avant que je ne formule une réponse ci-dessous.

Comment: (Ce serait en effet le même phénomène qui produit l'alternance "envoie" - "envoyer", sauf que là, l'addition de la syllabe qui rend obligatoire ce glissement est représentée au niveau orthographique, puisqu'elle est d'origine grammaticale et non stylistique.)

Comment: Comme le dit @LukeSawczak il s'agit d'une prononciation du *e* pour ajout d'une syllabe supplémentaire imposée par le rythme. Voir aussi [les réponses à cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/20050/358) sur la prononciation du e muet en poésie.

Comment: Merci pour vos réponses. Il s'agit alors d'une prononciation poétique. Ce qui m'a déconcerté sont de nombreux enregistrements même des ensembles français qui ne la respectent pas.

Comment: Cela pourrait être intéressant. Quels sont les vers affectés ? Peut-être que la syllabe est récupérée autre part, ou qu'on est un peu souple avec la métrique (voir le concept d'un « feminine ending » en anglais) ?

Comment: Ce sont les vers :
*La terre tournoie
Et fuit loin d'eux,
Quel bruit, quelle joie
Dans tous les yeux !*

J'en ai trouvé une ex. aussi dans les parties des solistes, où le [j] n'est toutefois pas écrit dans la transcription phonétique. J'ai séparé les syllabes terminales terminées par [ə] (chantées à une note spéciale).

*M: Non, monsieur ! Je ne suis pas demoisel-le ni bel-le ; demoisel-le ni bel-le,
Et je n'ai pas besoin qu'on me don-ne la main !
F: Par le ciel ! Que de grâ-ce, et de quel-le modesti-e !
O belle enfant ! Je t'ai-me... je t'ai-me, je t'ai-me !
S: Elle est parti-e !*

Comment: Mais selon cet enregistrement aussi, il est bien évident que ce deuxième exemple est plutôt mal transcrit : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKRITskQsLU

La scène se déroule à 3 minutes 25. Ils chantent [modesti-jə] et [parti-jə].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vu que tu remarques la présence de [j] en particulier, je ne résume que brièvement les circonstances qui lui donnent lieu, à savoir la prononciation du e muet [ə] : Comme l'explique Gilles dans sa réponse à [la question citée par Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/po%C3%A9sie-ponctuation-et-e-muet), ce phénomène se produit pour compléter la phrase musicale ou la métrique. Les paroliers font remarquer en effet la prononciation *normale* [en mettant une apostrophe](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tnks6vamryzsk5tyszkadaykva4?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) ! (Gilles note qu'un e muet à la fin d'un vers ne se prononce pas en poésie, mais lorsqu'on *chante*, cette syllabe peut même porter la melodie, p.ex. dans [cette chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avVZTj1rBTY) de Daniel Lavoie.)

Or ce qui résulte dans le cas de « tournoie » , c'est la juxtaposition de deux voyelles : [a] et [ə]. Cette situation est appelée le « [hiatus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistique)) » , et représente une difficulté articulatoire. Comme tu le verras en suivant ce lien-là, on résout ce problème de diverses façons : « ma âme » devient « mon âme » , tandis qu'on réalisera le [z] de « les » dans « les enfants » , etc.

Mais s'il s'agit de la réalisation spontanée (du point de vue grammatical) d'un e muet, il n'y aura pas de recours d'une consonne cachée  ou d'une forme alternative. Il s'ensuit souvent que la langue doit faire un « glissement » en articulant les deux voyelles à la suite. Ce glissemente décrit une [semi-voyelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-voyelle), appelée également une « glide » (le mot anglais en tête) pour cette raison. (Remarquons que ce n'est pas tout à fait inévitable et que le choix de la glide est influencé par le « i » historique.)

Tu pourrais l'essayer maintenant : prononce « joie » avec le e muet sans aucune pause, aussi vite que possible. Tu prononceras ou [ʒwa jə], ou [ʒwa ə] ; dans la deuxième prononciation les deux voyelles, voire les deux syllables, risqueront de se confondre un peu. De plus, une fois la règle apprise, cette prononciation est difficile à faire sans réflexion déliberée. Le [j] facilite l'articulation.

Ce phénomène est le même que ce qu'on constate dans l'alternance « tournoie » – « tournoyer » . La plupart du temps, quand tu rencontreras une telle paire, c'est que la présence d'une autre syllabe à l'infinitif ou dans d'autres conjugaisons (« tournoyons ») exige une semi-voyelle pour la lier à la syllabe précédente. Je crois que l'orthographe a été régularisée dans ce cas puisque le processus phonétique s'appuie sur un processus grammatique. Mais si « tournoie » se prononce « tournoye » en musique sans changement orthographique, je ne vois pas que cela serait interdit de nos jours.

P.S. Que les semi-voyelles agissent de cette manière a un impact pour le développement phonétique d'une langue. Par exemple, c'est pour des raisons semblables que « Iulius Cæsar » a perdu sa première syllable ; si c'était une fois [iu], cette combinaison ne peut que s'articuler [ju] avec le temps.