# Should I pronounce 'e' in the ending?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, e-caduc

I know that it is kind a like basics, but as I learned, e in the ending is not pronouncing, but I've listened Stromae's song "formidable" where he actually pronounces 'e' on the ending. Which variant is correct?

Comment: Un peu de lecture: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11944/13100, https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20060/13100, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/how-do-you-know-when-the-%C9%99-drops-and-when-it-doesnt

Answer (score 1):

In French, the letter e is often silent, such as at the end of a word, as in collège. There are several rules governing when e muet must be retained and when it must be deleted. Note however that retention or deletion also depends on the rapidity of speech, stylistic emphasis, and the type of consonants that precede or follow the e muet. 
See

https://www.laits.utexas.edu/fi/html/pho/11.html

[Poésie : Ponctuation et e muet](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/po%C3%A9sie-ponctuation-et-e-muet)

Also  « le e muet » is often not muet at all in songs, and almost never in poetry.

Comment: you're forgetting that « le e muet » is often not muet at all in songs, and almost never in poetry !!

Comment: @5915961T Thanks for the comment. I added your observation. Thanks also for all of your answers. As an advice, you should pick up a proper user name:-)!

Comment: @5915961T Regarding the poetry I included the link https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/po%C3%A9sie-ponctuation-et-e-muet when I answered the question. But I did not say anything about songs.

Comment: well, isn't Paul Van Haver alias Stromae a singer? But thanks for: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/po%C3%A9sie-ponctuation-et-e-muet. As for my pseudonym, well, I'm humble enough to hide behind a simple matricule number …   ;–)