# E muet suivi d’une virgule

Tags: poésie

J’aimerais savoir si lorsque l’on compte les pieds, une virgule après un *e* muet qui se prononcerait avec une voyelle est comptée ou non ?

Plus concrètement, une phrase telle que :

> Il pose son coude, imperturbable.

Se comptera-t-elle :

> « Il-po-se-son-cou-**de**-im-per-tur-ba-ble », soit 11 pieds ,

ou,

> « Il-po-se-son-cou-**d'im**-per-tur-ba-ble », soit 10 pieds ?

Comment: La question induite : « La virgule est-elle suivie d’une ’respiration’, d’une  pause dans la lecture de la phrase ? » … Question qui en cache une autre : « Le ***e*** est-il vraiment muet lorsqu’il est suivi d’une virgule et précédé d’une consonne ? »

Comment: Donc, si j’ai bien compris, c’est à l’auteur de prendre une certaine liberté selon le rythme de son texte. Après, pourquoi le e ne serait-il pas vraiment muet ?

Answer (score 1):

La présence d'une ponctuation ne change pas la règle du e muet. Il y a donc 10 syllabes dans ce vers.

Regarde cette [publication](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/po%C3%A9sie-ponctuation-et-e-muet) qui traitait déjà du sujet.